# Bookmaker odds and offers query

Tags: performance, sql, postgresql

The following query returns the latest `Odds` for each `Offer` based on the timestamp on the `Odds`. However, the query takes an average of 1497ms - and I'm sincerely asking for help to optimize it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("odds_odds"."offer_id")
    "odds_odds"."id", "odds_odds"."o1", "odds_odds"."o2", "odds_odds"."o3", "odds_offer"."odds_type_id", "odds_offer"."match_id", "odds_offer"."bookmaker_id" FROM "odds_odds"
INNER JOIN "odds_offer" ON ( "odds_odds"."offer_id" = "odds_offer"."id" )
INNER JOIN "odds_match" ON ( "odds_offer"."match_id" = "odds_match"."id" ) WHERE ("odds_match"."start_time" >= ? AND "odds_offer"."match_id" IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) AND ("odds_offer"."flags" = ? OR ("odds_offer"."flags" = ?
AND "odds_offer"."last_verified" >= ?)) AND NOT ((("odds_odds"."o1" = ? AND "odds_odds"."o1" IS NOT NULL) OR ("odds_odds"."o2" = ? AND "odds_odds"."o2" IS NOT NULL))))
ORDER BY "odds_odds"."offer_id" ASC, "odds_odds"."time" DESC
```

These are the stats from Heroku's log:

```
1497ms Avg. time
0/min Throughput
29ms I/O time
```

Here is the output from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)`:

```
Unique  (cost=342394.61..342394.61 rows=3 width=46) (actual time=46453.678..46703.724 rows=31430 loops=1)
   Output: odds_odds.id, odds_odds.o1, odds_odds.o2, odds_odds.o3, odds_offer.odds_type_id, odds_offer.match_id, odds_offer.bookmaker_id, odds_odds.offer_id, odds_odds."time"
   Buffers: shared hit=482834 read=24654 dirtied=9, temp read=1902 written=1902
   I/O Timings: read=93.940
   ->  Sort  (cost=342394.61..342394.61 rows=3 width=46) (actual time=46453.674..46580.738 rows=250485 loops=1)
         Output: odds_odds.id, odds_odds.o1, odds_odds.o2, odds_odds.o3, odds_offer.odds_type_id, odds_offer.match_id, odds_offer.bookmaker_id, odds_odds.offer_id, odds_odds."time"
         Sort Key: odds_odds.offer_id, odds_odds."time"
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 15208kB
         Buffers: shared hit=482834 read=24654 dirtied=9, temp read=1902 written=1902
         I/O Timings: read=93.940
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.11..342394.60 rows=3 width=46) (actual time=8.455..45710.497 rows=250485 loops=1)
               Output: odds_odds.id, odds_odds.o1, odds_odds.o2, odds_odds.o3, odds_offer.odds_type_id, odds_offer.match_id, odds_offer.bookmaker_id, odds_odds.offer_id, odds_odds."time"
               Buffers: shared hit=482827 read=24654 dirtied=9
               I/O Timings: read=93.940
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..342383.74 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=8.409..44383.739 rows=33436 loops=1)
                     Output: odds_offer.odds_type_id, odds_offer.match_id, odds_offer.bookmaker_id, odds_offer.id
                     Join Filter: (odds_offer.match_id = odds_match.id)
                     Rows Removed by Join Filter: 66691138
                     Buffers: shared hit=38450 read=24654 dirtied=9
                     I/O Timings: read=93.940
                     ->  Seq Scan on public.odds_offer  (cost=0.00..341815.13 rows=3222 width=16) (actual time=0.135..2791.383 rows=33922 loops=1)
                           Output: odds_offer.odds_type_id, odds_offer.match_id, odds_offer.bookmaker_id, odds_offer.id
                           Filter: ((odds_offer.flags OR ((NOT odds_offer.flags) AND (odds_offer.last_verified >= '2015-04-10 13:43:30.556949+00'::timestamp with time zone))) AND (odds_offer.match_id = ANY ('{2725665,2725667,2725670,2725671,2725674,2725668,2723416,2723423,2723421,2723422,3006845,3006846,3006848,2726643,2726644,2730552,2731247,2731250,2731248,2731249,2733487,2733490,2733740,2733741,2733742,2733743,2734281,2734286,2734288,2736599,2736600,2735768,2735770,2735769,2735773,2735767,2735772,2737269,2738308,2738309,3018437,3018441,3094187,3091835,2740985,2740982,2741303,2741304,2741309,2768481,2768487,2768483,2768482,2768488,2768485,2768484,2742802,3044541,2746058,2746057,2746063,2749068,2753763,2750377,2748517,3065622,2762436,2762437,2762439,2764009,2764320,3016595,2935111,2772316,2772318,2781140,2781144,2780837,2788433,3050601,3094643,3094641,2801042,2801044,2801047,2801048,2801049,2795387,2795390,2795388,2795389,2795395,2795391,2795392,2795394,2821571,2821729,2821730,2821731,2821732,2821733,2821735,2821736,2821738,2821739,2821740,2880288,2829676,2829678,2829679,2829680,2829681,2829682,2829683,2829685,3053895,2839492,2839497,2839501,2850609,2877859,2927855,2927848,2927852,2927854,2927850,3072825,2953872,2953874,3089862,3117521,3007435,3007428,3007427,3007430,3007436,3007444,3007445,3007442,3007446,3007447,3007448,3007429,3007449,3007431,2988273,3047885,3047887,3014213,3018787,3018790,3102572,3119336,3040014,3040020,3043864,3043861,3043862,3043865,3045244,3045245,3045246,3045247,3045248,3045249,3045250,3045251,3045252,3054436,3050931,3063078,3063079,3063080,3063081,3063082,3063083,3057971,3064730,3064731,3064732,3064733,3064734,3064735,3111903,3120490,3120446,3121373}'::integer[])))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 5523694
                           Buffers: shared hit=38116 read=24654 dirtied=9
                           I/O Timings: read=93.940
                     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..517.06 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.511 rows=1967 loops=33922)
                           Output: odds_match.id
                           Buffers: shared hit=334
                           ->  Seq Scan on public.odds_match  (cost=0.00..517.05 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=7.797..8.636 rows=1967 loops=1)
                                 Output: odds_match.id
                                 Filter: (odds_match.start_time >= '2015-04-10 13:53:30.556949+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 50333
                                 Buffers: shared hit=334
               ->  Index Scan using odds_odds_offer_id on public.odds_odds  (cost=0.11..10.68 rows=60 width=34) (actual time=0.014..0.033 rows=7 loops=33436)
                     Output: odds_odds.id, odds_odds.o1, odds_odds.o2, odds_odds.o3, odds_odds.offer_id, odds_odds."time"
                     Index Cond: (odds_odds.offer_id = odds_offer.id)
                     Filter: (((odds_odds.o1 <> 0::numeric) OR (odds_odds.o1 IS NULL)) AND ((odds_odds.o2 <> 0::numeric) OR (odds_odds.o2 IS NULL)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                     Buffers: shared hit=444377
 Total runtime: 46726.458 ms
```

Comment: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)` please.

Comment: Added `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Thanks for reviewing.

Comment: To give a proper answer I would need to see: Postgres version, table definitions and cardinalities (how many rows) for my answer. In particular: how many distinct `offer_id` and how many rows per `offer_id` in each table. Consider instructions in the related tag info on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 2):

#### Step 1: Human-readable, clean format

Especially for "code review". Most of your query string is noise. I also removed redundant parentheses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (o.offer_id)
       o.id, o.o1, o.o2, o.o3, f.odds_type_id, f.match_id, f.bookmaker_id
FROM   odds_offer f
JOIN   odds_odds  o ON o.offer_id = f.id
JOIN   odds_match m ON m.id = f.match_id
WHERE  NOT (o.o1 = ? AND o.o1 IS NOT NULL OR
            o.o2 = ? AND o.o2 IS NOT NULL)
AND    f.match_id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
AND   (f.flags = ? OR
       f.flags = ? AND f.last_verified >= ?)
AND    m.start_time >= ?
ORDER  BY o.offer_id, o."time" DESC;
```

#### Step 2: Simplify, fix

The expression `o.o1 = ? AND o.o1 IS NOT NULL` can be reduced to `o.o1 = ?`: if that evaluates to `true`, `o.o1` cannot be NULL.

And `NOT (o.o1 = ? OR o.o2 = ?)` can be replaced with `o.o1 <> ? AND o.o2 <> ?`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (f.id)
       o.id, o.o1, o.o2, o.o3, f.odds_type_id, f.match_id, f.bookmaker_id
FROM   odds_offer f
JOIN   odds_match m ON m.id = f.match_id
JOIN   odds_odds  o ON o.offer_id = f.id
WHERE  o.o1 <> ?
AND    o.o2 <> ?
AND    m.start_time >= ?
AND   (f.flags = ? OR
       f.flags = ? AND f.last_verified >= ?)
AND    f.match_id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ORDER  BY f.id, o."time" DESC NULLS LAST;
```

#### Step 3: Rewrite

I would need information as requested in the comment ...

My **educated guess** is that a `LATERAL` join would allow to use an index more efficiently.

Also, you have a *very long* list of matches for `match_id`. An `IN` construct is typically *inefficient* for long lists. Pass an array (or array literal), unnest IDs into a derived table and JOIN to it, that should be substantially faster. Detailed instructions:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91539/3684)

```
SELECT o.id, o.o1, o.o2, o.o3, f.odds_type_id, f.match_id, f.bookmaker_id
FROM   unnest (?) match_id   -- pass array of match_id
JOIN   odds_offer f USING (match_id)
JOIN   odds_match m ON m.id = f.match_id
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT id, o1, o2, o3
    FROM   odds_odds o
    WHERE  offer_id = f.id
    AND    o1 <> ?
    AND    o2 <> ?
    ORDER  BY o."time" DESC NULLS LAST
    LIMIT  1
    ) o ON true
WHERE (f.flags = ? OR
       f.flags = ? AND f.last_verified >= ?)
-- AND f.match_id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  -- replaced above
AND    m.start_time >= ?
ORDER  BY f.id, o."time" DESC NULLS LAST;
```

You need at least these two multicolumn **indices** (maybe another one on `odds_offer`):

```
odds_match (id, start_time DESC NULLS LAST)
odds_odds (offer_id, "time" DESC NULLS LAST, o1, o2, o3)
```

It only makes sense to appended the columns `o2, o3` if you get index-only scans out of it. Else don't.

Detailed instructions and explanation in this related answer on SO:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

Aside: don't use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like "time" as identifiers.